# Affine projection of polynomial

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Please i need your help to solve the following problem:

Let $V(Y)$ belong to $\mathbb{R}[Y_1,...,Y_d]$.

Prove that one can find an affine change of coordinate $Y=AX+B, (X_1,..,X_d)$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $n(V)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

1) for all $j\in \left\{ 1,..,n(V)\right\} \;we \;have\; \partial_{X_j}= constant$

2)for $j\in \left\{n(V)+1,..,d\right\}$, there existe $f_j\in \mathbb{R}[X_{j+1},...,X_d]$ such that

$X_j+f_j(X_{j+1},..,X_d)\in span\left\{\partial_x^{\alpha},|\alpha|\ge 1,\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^d\right\}$

Indication:consider the linear mapping $\partial_{y_j}, j=1,..,d$ which send the finite dimentional vector space $F_p=span\left\{\partial_Y^{\alpha}V,|\alpha|\ge p\right\}$ into $F_{p+1}$ and construct the $X_j$'s coordinate by reverse induction in a Jordan approch.